# Unity How to remove GameObject from list? Doesn't seem to be working for me

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

EDIT: fixed by adding `if(!roomsInProg.Contains(currentRoom)) roomsInProg.Add(currentRoom);` Thanks @derHugo!

So i'm working on a dungeon generator in Unity and in my script I'm adding the rooms i generate to a list of rooms that are in progress, then remove it when its done generating and start generating the next one on the list.

here i'm setting the current room

```
currentRoom = Instantiate(roomPrefabs[Random.Range(0, roomPrefabs.Length)], new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

then here i'm adding this room to the list of rooms in progress

```
roomsInProg.Add(currentRoom);
```

here is an example of me adding a new room that i spawned in to the list

```
if (roomScript.connectionsAvailable[0] == true && roomScript.rCheck[0].room == null && n<roomCount) {
        tempRoom = Instantiate(roomPrefabs[Random.Range(0, roomPrefabs.Length)], new Vector3(0, roomDistanceY, 0) + currentRoom.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        roomsInProg.Add(tempRoom);
        tempRoom.GetComponent<RoomScript>().directionFromSpawn = 0;
        n++;
        if (n>=roomCount) {
            firstOver = true;
        }
        }
```

and here i am removing the current room from the list

```
if (!firstOver) {
        roomsInProg.Remove(currentRoom);
        currentRoom = roomsInProg[0];
    }
    if (n<roomCount || roomsInProg.Count > 0) {
        Invoke("SpawnRoom", 0.01f);
    }
    }
```

Here is the entire code, if necessary https://pastebin.com/C9TKnQPL
Other Scripts if necessary RoomScript [pastebin.com/HPSFJ7RB](http://pastebin.com/HPSFJ7RB) roomCheck [pastebin.com/umNvj9VG](http://pastebin.com/umNvj9VG) SpawnCheck [pastebin.com/xkT7QtSJ](http://pastebin.com/xkT7QtSJ)

Comment: You should add your RoomScript and SpawnCheck scripts also.

Comment: Ok, the SpawnCheck script doesn't even do anything, it marks the spawn room, but for some reason all the other ones pass the if statement too even tho they arent the spawn room :/ idk its weird. 
RoomScript https://pastebin.com/HPSFJ7RB
roomCheck https://pastebin.com/umNvj9VG
SpawnCheck https://pastebin.com/xkT7QtSJ

Comment: @Saif if you need me to add comments to my code, tell me, i understand its probably a pain without them

Comment: why are you creating a new list every time you add something to your lists?

Comment: Additionally, why are you converting your lists to arrays?

Comment: sorry for the confusion @Josh this was just something i put in as a test with hopes of fixing it, because i saw it on another post, originally i had only one list that was changed, but the outcome is the same. I have went back to having only one list, but it still doesn't work. My code is kinda messy because of all these "fixes" that i tried to put in, that in the end didn't even help

Comment: it should actually be possible to simply do `roomsInProg.Remove(currentRoom);` and use only one list ... if it was just a test maybe first cleanup the code and post here the original attempt that didn't work for you instead of posting a very cluttered version where you somehow tried to workaround ...

Comment: @derHugo done, fixed up the post and the pastebin link, sorry about that

Comment: It pretty much looks like you actually rather want to use a [`Queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue) which is specifically made for first-in | first-out implementations.

Comment: Your code is too long and confusing for me to parse it all .. but .. is it possible you add the `currentRoom` multiple times so when you remove it there is still one left so `roomsInProg[0]` stays the same room? Maybe before adding it you should make sure it is not already there: `if(!roomsInProg.Contains(currentRoom)) roomsInProg.Add(currentRoom);`

Comment: @derHugo The queue did not work, but checking if its already on the list did, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `Spawn` method where you have

```
Invoke("SpawnRoom", 0.01f);
```

Then in `SpawnRoom` you do

```
roomsInProg.Add(currentRoom);
```

honestly I didn't parse you entire code but the very last thing in `SpawnRoom` you do is

```
if (n<roomCount || roomsInProg.Count > 0) {
    Invoke("SpawnRoom", 0.01f);
}
```

So without me knowing what happens in between it seems very possible to me that `roomsInProg.Count` is `> 0` at the end which causes you to again call `SpawnRoom` and add the same `currentRoom` to the list again.

You should check if it already exists and only add it if not like

```
if(!roomsInProg.Contains(currentRoom)) roomsInProg.Add(currentRoom);
```

---

In general you should strongly rethink your code structure and in particular these `Invoke` calls ... you probably might be better using a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). Most of your `if else` blocks should either be replaced by `switch-case` or even better use some dictionaries in order to translate your input indececes to the ones you later want to access. This way your code could be trastically reduced.

---

Just as one example

Instead of using

```
if (currentRoom.GetComponentInChildren<SpawnCheck>().spawnRoom == false) {
    if (roomScript.directionFromSpawn == 0) {
        availableDoors.Remove(availableDoors[System.Array.IndexOf(availableDoors.ToArray(), 2)]);
        roomScript.connectionsEnabled[2] = true;
        roomScript.connectionsAvailable[2] = false;
        roomScript.connectionsConnected[2] = false;
        roomScript.roomConnections[2].SetActive(false);
    }
    if (roomScript.directionFromSpawn == 1) {
        availableDoors.Remove(availableDoors[System.Array.IndexOf(availableDoors.ToArray(), 3)]);
        roomScript.connectionsEnabled[3] = true;
        roomScript.connectionsAvailable[3] = false;
        roomScript.connectionsConnected[3] = false;
        roomScript.roomConnections[3].SetActive(false);
    }
    if (roomScript.directionFromSpawn == 2) {
        availableDoors.Remove(availableDoors[System.Array.IndexOf(availableDoors.ToArray(), 0)]);
        roomScript.connectionsEnabled[0] = true;
        roomScript.connectionsAvailable[0] = false;
        roomScript.connectionsConnected[0] = false;
        roomScript.roomConnections[0].SetActive(false);
    }
    if (roomScript.directionFromSpawn == 3) {
        availableDoors.Remove(availableDoors[System.Array.IndexOf(availableDoors.ToArray(), 1)]);
        roomScript.connectionsEnabled[1] = true;
        roomScript.connectionsAvailable[1] = false;
        roomScript.connectionsConnected[1] = false;
        roomScript.roomConnections[1].SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

I would do

```
private Dictionary<int,int> directionToConnectionIndex = new Dictionary<int, int>
    {
        {0, 2},
        {1, 3},
        {2, 0},
        {3, 1}
    };
```

which allows you to reduce the entire block to just

```
if (!currentRoom.GetComponentInChildren<SpawnCheck>().spawnRoom) 
{   
    var connectionIndex = directionToConnectionIndex[roomScript.directionFromSpawn];

    availableDoors.Remove(connectionIndex);

    roomScript.connectionsEnabled[connectionIndex] = true;
    roomScript.connectionsAvailable[connectionIndex] = false;
    roomScript.connectionsConnected[connectionIndex] = false;
    roomScript.roomConnections[connectionIndex].SetActive(false);
}
```

Maybe even use some `enum`s in orser to limit down the possible values.

Comment: Massive thanks for the help, and also thank you for the shortened code, I disliked the long code, but I'm a noob so I didn't know if possible/how to make the code shorter.